Why the sibling directory is not registered using module-alias in node?
I want to have clear imports. I searched and found module-alias package. It seems that it's the only package.
I need to register aliases dynamically. This is my code:
import "module-alias/register.js"

import * as path from "path"
import * as url from "url"
import moduleAlias from "module-alias"

const __filename = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)

const corePath = path.join(__dirname, "core")
console.log(corePath)
moduleAlias.addAlias("core", corePath)

import { parseArgs } from "core"

I get this error:
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:854
  throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(packageName, fileURLToPath(base), null);
        ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'core' imported from app.js
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:854:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:927:18)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1169:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:542:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:510:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:239:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:96:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:95:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v20.18.1

This is my project structure:

app.js
package.json
core

parseArgs.js
index.js (barrel file)



This is a simple setup to make it work. The real project would be different. I have a core directory sibling to my entry point js file (sibling to the package.json) and I have a simple barrel in it.
Why do I get that error. How can I solve it?

This cannot be done in a single module because import statements are hoisted. Everything but the last line needs to be extracted to a separate module, then it would be:
import './register-aliases';
import { parseArgs } from "core"
...


I moved those lines to another file, called that file aliases.js and in my app.js I imported it at the top like import './aliases.js' and I still get that error that the core package can not be found.

What node version do you use? module-alias is aimed at older node versions, I'd expect it to do nothing for esm in the latest version due to the way it works. See https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias/issues/113

My node version is 'v20.18.1'. I added "#core": "./core" to the imports in the package.json file and it worked. I wish module-alias has mentioned that at the top of their README file.
